# Tab is not working in window application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a two Textbox in my application one is `txtCampaign` and second is `txtUrl`. The TabIndex for `txtCampaign` is 1 and TabIndex for `txtUrl` is 2.

Now I have used the following code:

```
 private void txtCampaign_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        txtCampaign.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        txtUrl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
 }

 private void txtUrl_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       txtUrl.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
       txtCampaign.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
 }
```

Now when i used the Tab from 1st Text box `txtCampaign` it will not allow me to go to the second Textbox.

I am not sure why this happen? But if i remove above code its working fine for me

Comment: I don't know either. It may be that the textbox you are in looses focus when you set the new `BorderStyle` value. Try to call `txtBox.Focus()` in the event handler as well. If that doesn't your next try is to reset the `TabOrder` value in the eventhandler as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SetFocus() in your events. Sample code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Enter += textBox1_Enter;
    textBox2.Enter += textBox2_Enter;
}

private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    textBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    textBox2.Focus();
}

private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    textBox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    textBox1.Focus();
}
```